# Android Studio, почему не работает этот код? Я же всё по книге сделал

Tags: android

[image: Android_Studio_error_code]
Android Studio, почему не работает этот код? Я же всё по книге сделал

Comment: Если хотите получить внятный ответ, напишите более развернутый вопрос: Что должно быть, что не получается. И код, желательно, выкладывать не в виде скрина экрана.

Comment: Потому что объявление переменной textt и обращение к ней происходит в разных областях видимости.

Comment: Мы могли бы вам помочь, внеся исправления в код и объяснив в чём дело, но не можем скопировать код с картинки. Выложите его текстом.

Comment: Кажется автор использует в xml разметке атрибут onClick. Так можно любой метод активити указать, если указан контекст. Эдакая альтернатива лисенеру для начинающих

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам IDE подсвечивает виновника. Это переменная textt. Вы ее объявляете внутри функции onCreate, и вне этой функции она не доступна. Вынесите ее из функции

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private TextView textt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
         textt = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    }

    public void clickMyButton(View view){
         textt.setText("oh shit")
    }
}
```